# Telnet Port connectivity from one server to another through JSP

Tags: linux, jsp, unix, telnet, zos

Hi All,

I want to create a JSP page where I will ask user to give the source host and port and also destination host and port.
Following combination of source and destination OS is possible

- Unix->Unix/Windows/zOS Windows-> Unix/Windows/zOS zOS ->
  Unix/Windows/zOS

With these inputs I want to connect to the source server and fire this command telnet $ip $port  to the destination. If the telnet connectivity is successful it should return success and else error.

I want to create the logic non-interactive that it should not require any password to login the source for checking telnet connectivity. 
Is there any such library or any mechanism available so that I could make this feasible?

Comment: And then what? How is the client at his browser going to type into a telnet running on another server?

Comment: That is what my question is.  Is that feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)?

```
TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();

try {
  telnet.connect("rainmaker.wunderground.com", 3000);
} catch(IOException e) {
  // failed
} finally {
  telnet.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I will check it and revert. I think the above code will check the telnet connectivity of either source or receiver from the server where my Java application is hosted. My application is hosted on different server and from this application I want to check the telnet connectivity from different source server to different receiver server

Comment: You could wrap the telnet client in a simple web service, deploy it on your app server and execute it from your web app.

Comment: Thanks... haven't tried it yet.. will surely tell the outcome of this once I start this approach.